# Yii - activeRecord - with adds an automatic orderby clause

Tags: activerecord, yii

I try to find out why and where "orderBy" clause is added when I do a with (CDCriteria) but nothing on the Internet and unable to find in the code..

I have 3 tables defining place types (id, name for each):
Category > Activity > Specialty

I have a table place :

id | name | place_type_id | place_type_spe_id

I have several defined relations in Place model:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(

        'placeType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PlaceType', 'place_type_id'),
        'placeTypeSpecialty' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PlaceTypeSpecialty', 'place_type_specialty_id'),           
    );
}
```

Defined relations in PlaceType (actiivty) model :

```
  public function relations() {
    return array(           
        'places' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Place', 'place_secondary_type(place_type_id, place_id)'),
        'placeTypeCategory' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'PlaceTypeCategory', 'place_type_category_id'),
        'placeTypeSpecialties' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'PlaceTypeSpecialty', 'place_type_id'),
    );
```

I would like to search keywords in place name, relative activity name, relative specialty name and relative category name (depending on activity..).

I tried :

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->with = array('placeType', 'placeType.placeTypeSpecialties', 'placeType.placeTypeCategory');
    $criteria->together = true;


    $words = StringHelper::parseKeywords($keywords);


    $keywordsCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
    foreach ($words as $w) {
        $wordCriteria = new CDbCriteria();

        $wordCriteria->compare('t.name', $w, true, 'OR');
        $wordCriteria->compare('placeTypeCategory.name', $w, true, 'OR');
        $wordCriteria->compare('placeTypeCategory.expression', $w, true, 'OR');
        $wordCriteria->compare('placeType.name', $w, true, 'OR');
        $wordCriteria->compare('placeType.common_words', $w, true, 'OR');
        $wordCriteria->compare('placeTypeSpecialties.name', $w, true, 'OR');
        $keywordsCriteria->mergeWith($wordCriteria, 'OR');
    }

    $criteria->mergeWith($keywordsCriteria);

    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith($criteria);
    return $this;
```

But... SQL query failed because of :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'name' in order clause is ambiguous.
```

And the ORDER BY clause is :

```
ORDER BY distance ASC, placeType.name ASC, name ASC
```

"name" is obviously ambigous but I dont' want to order by this field ! Adding `$criteria->with = array('placeType.placeTypeCategory');` adds this order by clause..

My questions are :

Why this is added and how to ignore it..
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you change the column name to other name than `name`? I mean, since it is one of MySQL keywords..

Comment: Nothing happens. Still the same error. If I add a new relation (in with) SQL adds an order by. 

For  $criteria->with = array('placeType') it adds "ORDER BY placeType.name"

For  $criteria->with = array('placeType.placeTypeSpecialties') it adds nothing..

For  $criteria->with = array('placeTypeCategory') it adds "ORDER BY name"

Weird..

Comment: OMG I found out the problem.. In PlaceTypeCategory model the previous developer has added : <code>     public function defaultScope()
    {
      return array(
        'order' => 'name ASC'
      );
    } </code> ! Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

The previous developper has added, in PlaceTypeCategory model, a defaultScope function :

```
    public function defaultScope()
{
  return array(
    'order' => 'name ASC'
  );
}
```

I did not know this possibility.